# Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'. Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, jitpack, android-jetpack-compose-list

I want to build a library with Jetpack Compose and publishing it using jitpack.io.
Im using the canary version of android studio
[android studio canary version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaPxy.png).
I've build the project, push it to Github, made a release then I've put the link of my repo in jitpack.io to generate the lib dependency link "implementation 'com.github.user:compose-lib:Tag'" but something went wrong and I got this log error from jitpack :

```
Build starting...
Start: Tue Apr 27 14:25:17 UTC 2021 0c5235afbe25
Git:
0.9.0-0-g13dbaf9
commit 13dbaf941d2c59d8e70ed64b868488abb7f3f2e1
Author: username 
Date:   Tue Apr 27 14:29:45 2021 +0200

    gradle plugin require Java 11 to run


Found Android manifest
Android SDK version: . Build tools: 30.0.3
Installing Build-tools 30.0.3 
Found gradle
Gradle build script
Found gradle version: 7.0.
Using gradle wrapper
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-rc-1-bin.zip
.
Unzipping /home/jitpack/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.0-rc-1-bin/14lahl8r8vkgd4j5n81i3rsld/gradle-7.0-rc-1-bin.zip to /home/jitpack/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.0-rc-1-bin/14lahl8r8vkgd4j5n81i3rsld
Set executable permissions for: /home/jitpack/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.0-rc-1-bin/14lahl8r8vkgd4j5n81i3rsld/gradle-7.0-rc-1/bin/gradle

Welcome to Gradle 7.0-rc-1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - File system watching enabled by default
 - Support for running with and building Java 16 projects
 - Native support for Apple Silicon processors
 - Dependency catalog feature preview

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.0-rc-1/release-notes.html


------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.0-rc-1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-03-23 01:02:30 UTC
Revision:     f5bf7ade373b74058e49f07749083b4c3075549a

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_252 (Private Build 25.252-b09)
OS:           Linux 4.14.63-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 amd64

0m3.102s
Getting tasks: ./gradlew tasks --all
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/jitpack/build/mylib/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.library']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Tasks: 

WARNING:
Gradle 'install' task not found. Please add the 'maven' or 'android-maven' plugin.
See the documentation and examples: https://jitpack.io/docs/

Adding maven plugin
Found android library build file in mylib
Running: ./gradlew clean -Pgroup=com.github.user -Pversion=0.9.0 install
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

> Configure project :
Gradle version Gradle 7.0-rc-1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/jitpack/build/mylib/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.library']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0-rc-1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Build tool exit code: 0
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
2021-04-27T14:25:58.25891409Z
Exit code: 0

ERROR: No build artifacts found
```

And here my build.gradle file of my library:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.4.32"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-beta05"
    }
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
    }
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha07'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
}
```

I changed the java version from 1.8 to 11 but still doesn't work.

here my android studio config: [Gradle JDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzoVW.png)

File > project structure > SDK Location: [SDK Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlzUY.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

**[EDIT] Problem Solved** by configuring Jitpack to run on Java 11. I added jitpack.yml file which contains

```
jdk:
  - openjdk11
```

You can refer to this [article](https://ayoubbenkhemis.medium.com/publish-android-library-with-jitpack-be00a29a8174) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Is the path to JDK correct? You could check inside File > project structure > sdk location.
please verify if this location is based on jdk 11.

Comment: I don't see any JDK in File > project structure > sdk location, I have only Android SDK location and Android NDK location. I updated my question with an image to SDK Location you can see it.

Comment: did you download and install JDK 11 from Java official site and set its global path?

Comment: Yeah, I have this output when calling java --version : openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.11.9.1 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.11.9.1 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS, mixed mode)

Comment: please verify with this link, if you have correctly setup JDK path for studio:
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config